# Converting SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I'm trying to convert the following statement from SQL Server to Oracle, but everything I've tried gives me different errors. Does anyone know how to convert this to be oracle friendly?

```
select 
    nullif(cast(cast(round(vn02.wheelbase,0,1)-1 as integer) as varchar) + ',' +
      cast(cast(round(vn02.wheelbase,0,1) as integer) as varchar) + ',' + 
      cast(cast(round(vn02.wheelbase,0,1)+1 as integer) as varchar),'-1,0,1') wheelbase
from vn02_fullsv vn02
```

wheel base if a float, and it needs to be appended to itself with comma delimiters to see if it equals '-1,0,1' and if so then it should return null.

thanks for the help.

Comment: Unless the column is declared as a a BINARY_DOUBLE or BINARY_FLOAT, it won't actually be a native floating point number, but a decimal number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be close to what you are looking for:

```
select (decode(round(vn02.wheelbase,0)-1||','||round(vn02.wheelbase,0)||','||round(vn02.wheelbase,0)+1, '-1,0,1', null,vn02.wheelbase)
from vn02_fullsv vn02;
```

The '||' replace the + to concatenate the strings, and decode replaces the nullif.
Round works the same as your example.

Here are is a link for a reference on [Decode](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php) and here is a reference for [Round](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/round_nbr.php).

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried it and I got an error saying too many arguments for function, which was referring to the round function. So I changed that and now I just get and "invalid number" error. Any ideas? Here's the new statement:

select decode((round(vn02.wheelbase)-1||','||round(vn02.wheelbase)||','||round(vn02.wheelbase)+1), '-1,0,1', null,vn02.wheelbase)
from vn02_fullsv vn02;

Comment: @pwnerer sorry about that, I have it fixed now. That should work. Basically round works by telling it to round to # of decimals. So this rounds to nearest whole number. The only issue I see with that is if you have say 1.6 it will return 2. Not sure if that will be an issue for you, it depends on the data you have.

Comment: Thanks jschoen. I was still getting the invalid number error, but the reason was becasue a bunch of casting needed to be done. I updated the SQL with the working one. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @pwnerer Glad I could help. While I do not normally request upvotes or to have my answers marked as accepted, I will this time since you are new. If my answer helped you, give an upvote, if it actually answered your question marked it as answered. If it did not answer your question, you should add your own answer with the correct answer. This will help others in the future that come across this, to know what worked for you.